# Why does HtmlElementEventArgs.ToElement return null?

Tags: c#, system.web

I am trying to detect a certain element when it's clicked in a web browser.

Here's my code:

```
try
{
   htmlElement.MouseDown -= new 
   HtmlElementEventHandler(webBrowser1_MouseDown);
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
htmlElement.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(webBrowser1_MouseDown);
```

This code is called on webBrowser1.GotFocus & webBrowser1.LostFocus.

Here is the code for MouseDown.

```
    public void webBrowser1_MouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement element = e.ToElement;
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
```

For some reason whenever I click on the item. element is equal to null?

but if I do

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine(htmlElement.Name); // works
    htmlElement.MouseDown -= new 
    HtmlElementEventHandler(webBrowser1_MouseDown);
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
htmlElement.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(webBrowser1_MouseDown);
```

Comment: What you receive in `e` is `HtmlElementEventArgs` not any element. I would suggest you to use `sender` object to get the element.

Comment: I just realized this before you commented this, it made me mad so much that i spent 30 minutes trying to figure this out. Sorry I'm quite new to System.Web.

Comment: That is fine. Did using `sender` solve your problem?

Comment: Yea it did. @GaurangDave

Comment: Please don't put things like 'SOLVED' in your title, even when it's solved. Just accept the answer and the normal SO indicators will show it's solved

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks and noted. Just wanted to confirmed whether it  helped or not.

Comment: @Voided I put the same as answer below. Kindly mark as answer/upvote if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I noticed in code you shared, you can fix them very easily.

1. `htmlElement` - you declared this on Page and registered `MouseDown` event with it. You can access it anywhere in the page. There is no need of another `HtmlElement` object in the event.
2. What you receive in `e` is `HtmlElementEventArgs` not any element. I would suggest you to use `sender` object to get the element.